# Using express.static middleware in an authorized route

Tags: node.js, express, node.js-connect

I'm using node with express and passportjs to restrict access to files located in a private folder. I have reduced my code to the following.
Everything in the public static folder works great but route targeting the private folder through the use of the staticMiddleware returns 404 errors.

```
var express = require('express')
,   util = require('util');

var app = express.createServer();
var staticMiddleware = express.static(__dirname + '/private');

app.configure(function() {
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.logger('dev')); 
  app.use('/public',express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

app.get('/private/:file', function(req, res, next){
    console.log('about to send restricted file '+ req.params.file);
    staticMiddleware(req, res, next);
});
app.listen(16000);
```

I was using the following references that seems to work for others, so I must be missing something.
It won't work for me showing only 404 responses for the content located in the private area.

[Node.js module-specific static resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746180/node-js-module-specific-static-resources)

[NodeJS won't serve static files, even when using express.static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646406/nodejs-wont-serve-static-files-even-when-using-express-static)

[Redirecting to a static file in express.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9457511/redirecting-to-a-static-file-in-express-js)

I could have sworn I had this working before, maybe it was broken in a new version of something.

- Node v0.8.1
- npm 1.1.12
- express@2.5.11
- connect@1.9.2

Comment: I was looking for the exact same thing. Had a few ideas on how to do it, but thanks for answering it yourself. This was a very nice solution.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

sheesh staring at me the whole time

```
app.get('/private/:file', function(req, res, next){
    console.log('about to send restricted file '+ req.params.file);
    req.url = req.url.replace(/^\/private/, '')
    staticMiddleware(req, res, next);
});
```

Edit 11-29-2014

So after someone posted to the question I came back to this answer to find that even though I mention passportjs I never showed how I ended up using this function.

```
var staticMiddlewarePrivate = express['static'](__dirname + '/private');

app.get('/private/*/:file', auth.ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res, next){
    console.log('**** Private ****');
    req.url = req.url.replace(/^\/private/, '');
    staticMiddlewarePrivate(req, res, next);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add `express.static(__dirname + '/private');` to your app.config.

```
app.configure(function() {
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.logger('dev')); 
  app.use('/public',express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
  app.use('/private',express.static(__dirname + '/private'));
});
```

The `private` path middleware would be executed anytime a path began with `private`.

Comment: This would expose the static files correctly, but it wouldn't keep them password protected. My understanding is that @eephillip wanted to have them served but also password protected through passwordJS.